# How can I deserialize properties which don't have an in built converter?

Tags: delphi, serialization, properties

This is a spin off from my last question
[How does delphi convert ModalResult properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3388014/how-does-delphi-convert-modalresult-properties/)

Since Delphi doesn't convert ModalResult properties, what's the best way for me to convert ModalResult properties to integers?

I don't really want:

```
If SpecialCase then
else if AnotherSpecialCase then
else BehaveNormally
```

So how do I convert values such as `'mrOk'` into `1`?

Note: I'm using

```
PropInfo := GetPropInfo(Instance, PropertyName);
SetPropValue(Instance, PropInfo, PropertyValue);
```

to set the property values.

Delphi 2007

Comment: What version of Delphi are you using?  As Delphi 2010 has a better way to do some of this than previous versions.

Comment: I don't understand what to convert, mrOk is already 1. You can `PropertyValue := mrOk` or `SetPropValue(Instance, PropInfo, mrOk)`.

Comment: Doesn't your own answer to your other question help?

Comment: @Uwe - Yes! it does.  But Rob pointed out it's a different question and told me to post it as such

Comment: @Sertac - When serialized mrOK isn't a constant, it's a string and SetPropValue(Instance, PropInfo, 'mrOk') fails.

Comment: @James - The question is not stated correctly then, you want to convert `'mrOk'` to 1, not `mrOk` to 1.

Comment: Maybe I should be asking "How do I ask a clear question" - anyway, updated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no converter for ModalResults, Delphi stores the Integer representation in the DFM. As a solution I've registered a new converter

```
const
  ModalResults: array[0..10] of TIdentMapEntry = (
    (Value: mrNone; Name: 'mrNone'),           
    (Value: mrOk; Name: 'mrOk'),               
    (Value: mrCancel; Name: 'mrCancel'),       
    (Value: mrAbort; Name: 'mrAbort'),         
    (Value: mrRetry; Name: 'mrRetry'),         
    (Value: mrIgnore; Name: 'mrIgnore'),       
    (Value: mrYes; Name: 'mrYes'),             
    (Value: mrNo; Name: 'mrNo'),               
    (Value: mrAll; Name: 'mrAll'),             
    (Value: mrNoToAll; Name: 'mrNoToAll'),     
    (Value: mrYesToAll; Name: 'mrYesToAll'));



function ModalResultToIdent(ModalResult: Longint; var Ident: string): Boolean;
begin
    Result := IntToIdent(ModalResult, Ident, ModalResults);
end;

function IdentToModalResult(const Ident: string; var ModalResult: Longint): Boolean;
begin
    Result := IdentToInt(Ident, ModalResult, ModalResults);
end;
initialization
    RegisterIntegerConsts(TypeInfo(TModalResult), IdentToModalResult, ModalResultToIdent);
```